# Running android using device connected to usb

Tags: java, android

can I somehow run the android project currently running using my phone that is connected via usb?
the android emulator starts pretty slow so i think it would be better to use my device

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. install the proper usb driver (this might not be necessary on a mac)
2. turn on Developer mode on your device ( settings->applications->development )
3. plug in the device to your computer
4. wait for the device to show up on the devices list ( [android-sdk-folder/tools/]adb devices or check out the DDMS panel in eclipse )
5. run the app..

Answer (score 1):

U will have to install the required driver.. and connect the phone.. the adb will get installed..now run the app manually(in run configuration).. there u can see all device in which u can run your app.. select yourr device.. and app will run in the phone.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing with eclipse the ADT plugin is your friend. To run/debug your app on your phone you have to download the drivers for your phone and install them. Then your phone should appear as an emulator in the DDSM perspective inside eclipse. When you now run/debug your app, eclipse will choose your phone as the target.

P.S. You have to enable usb debugging:

1. From the home screen, press the Menu button below the screen.
2. Tap the Settings option.
3. Choose Applications.
4. Select Development.
5. Check the box for USB Debugging to turn it on.

Answer (score 0):

A complete description for all platforms (Windows, Linux, Mac) of how to use a real device for debugging can be found here
http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html

A list for all common manufacturers of where to get the USB driver from is located here
http://developer.android.com/sdk/oem-usb.html